# Does RazorMachine support forloops

Tags: c#, .net, template-engine, razorengine

Does rajor machine  [razormachine](https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine) 
Support for loop , is there any example in that 
Following didnt work

```
md.Title = "Title";
            md.TableDt.Add(new TableData { Name = "name1" });
            md.TableDt.Add(new TableData { Name = "name2" });
            RazorMachine rm = new RazorMachine();
            ITemplate template = rm.ExecuteContent(
                @"Razor says:@@ok Hello @Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName
            @foreach (var v in Model.TableDt)
{
v.Name
}
            ",
              new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });
            Console.WriteLine(template.Result);
```

Comment: Please add it in answer section ,I would accept it,its correct and it works , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you want the name of the variable `v` to be printed.
If so, you are forgetting that you would need to prepend an `@` symbol.

The correct code would be:

```
md.Title = "Title";
md.TableDt.Add(new TableData { Name = "name1" });
md.TableDt.Add(new TableData { Name = "name2" });
RazorMachine rm = new RazorMachine();
ITemplate template = rm.ExecuteContent(
    @"Razor says:@@ok Hello @Model.FirstName  @Model.LastName
      @foreach (var v in Model.TableDt)
      {
          @v.Name
      }
",
  new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" });
Console.WriteLine(template.Result);
```